# How to convert zulu datetime format to user defined time format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime-format

Hi I have this DateTime format in our log "2019-09-19T15:12:59.943Z"
I want to convert this to custom DateTime format 2019-09-19 15:12:59

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = "2019-09-19T15:12:59.943Z"
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print("dt_object =", dt_object)
print("type(dt_object) =", type(dt_object))
```

which function shall I use for this
thanks

Comment: from where you got  `2019-09-19T15:12:59.943Z` this kind of datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay

This issue is related to custom DateTime formatting not related to timestamp.
because `timestamp` in python is an integer value, not a string value.
So you have a custom `DateTime` format which contains `Zulu` time format. 
and you need to convert this `Zulu DateTime` format to custom DateTime format.

so, try this python script and its working fine on Python version 3.6

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-09-19T15:12:59.943Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

new_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
d.strftime(new_format)

print(d)
```

or you can use this online fiddle to check the result

https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/c7b8e849-c31a-41ba-8bc9-5436d6faa4e9/?i=true